# Is this a learning to rank problem?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, ordinal-data, ranking, supervised-learning

I'm stuck on a problem I'm trying to "translate" into ML terms so as to dig deeper into the literature.

**Setup**
I have *n* samples for which I generate *k* $\in (0, 40]$ different low-dimensional representations ($\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{7}$) using various simulation/scoring methods.
I have a ground-truth ranking of all *n* samples.

**Problem**
Let the score of a particular representation be some linear combination ($\Sigma ~ w_ix_i$) of the 7 features. I want to learn a set of weights $\mathbf{w}$ such that the best representation of each sample ranks according to my ground truth. $\mathbf{w}$ is very important here as I want the relative contribution/importance of these features for downstream tasks.

**Question**
What sort of problem is this? There's an aspect of learning-to-rank but it's not quite formulated in the same way as many of your typical ltr problems are...

Any help/papers/tips are much appreciated!

Comment: Possibly helpful: [What is the difference between ordinal regression and ranking?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/41368/1352)